# Has anyone reverse engineered the bluetooth protocol of a Mackie Thump GO loudspeaker?

Tags: bluetooth

I want to remote-control my Mackie Thump GO loudspeaker without using the official app, so that I can build an app that can control music and the speaker at the same time (and maybe even do some automation). Has anyone reverse engineered the bluetooth protocol of a Mackie Thump GO loudspeaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the protocol was reverse engineered. The results can be found at https://gist.github.com/mhasdf/489c6d35c830dda512143d0374bb17ce

Comment: Self answered :))

Comment: It was quite some work and I thought: Why not share? Maybe somebody else will find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! If this is your work, you can post this in your blog!